# how to save a video file on local hard disk from the blob using File Saver in java script?

Tags: javascript, blob, fileapi, filesaver.js

I have written code to download the video from GoogleCloud storage

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function(){ 
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/test/xyzzzzz.mp4";
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/test/xyzzzzz.mp4', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
}
```

How to get the blob object? and then how do I save to local hard disk using File Saver ? What should I pass to the File Saver Saveas() method. I went through File API documentation but I couldn't get it working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`xhr.response` holds the value returned by your callback to Google Storage, so that's what you'd pass in. `Filesaver saveas(xhr.response, filename)`

You didn't ask about cross-browser compatibility, but you should be aware that blob may not be supported by all browsers. You might want to build a blob instead of setting blob as the response type, like this:

```
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"
blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "video/mp4"});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried saveAs(blob,'test.mp4'), but I recieved this error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined"

Comment: This is resolved by adding Filsaver.js but when I saved video file like this blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "video/mp4"}); nothing is saved and video is not played.

Comment: `xhr.response` is the attribute that holds the server response from your http request. I don't know what that returned data looks like because I'm not in your app, but you can find out by printing `xhr.response` in the console. You may need to deserialize the returned data or select an element from the data.